# Certificate issue with Curl

Tags: linux, unix, ssl, centos, rhel

My CentOS 7 server which is in AWS private cloud (company network), is unable to connect to some sites. After some work I managed to narrow the problem down to following problem.

(1) The following internal site is not accessible (SSL by public CA):

```
curl -v https://git.example.com
```

which returns:

```
About to connect() to git.example.com port 443 (#0)
Trying 10.62.124.6...
Connected to git.example.com (10.62.124.6) port 443 (#0)
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
```

(2) But following internal site works (SSL by public CA):

```
curl -v https://alm.example.com
```

which returns:

```
About to connect() to alm.example.com port 443 (#0)
Trying 10.64.167.137...
Connected to alm.example.com (10.64.167.137) port 443 (#0)
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
...
...
...
Accept: */*
```

Any idea why number (1) is not working? These are both internal sites trusted by same public CA.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: With so little information (no CA details, no certificate content, etc.) I doubt anyone could help you and in all cases your question is not very related to programming. Start by comparing differences in certificates content, subject, issuer, dates, extensions. Also you are not even specifying what is happening at next steps for your first case...

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be the following case in our company.
git.example.com was hosted in private Azure and
alm.example.com was hosted in private AWS. And my working server also happens to be in AWS which is why the Azure one was having some trouble in the network. As advised by network team I set the MTU size in linux kernal to 1350 and this was resolved.

Moreover, our company had also started intercepting SSL traffic for which they have installed a intermediate certificate in the proxy and expect all internal servers to trust this certificate. My problem stated above was due to mix of both of these issues, where the certificate issue could have been sorted by trusting it or ignoring SSL verification.

Hope this helps someone.